# Can't get variable to pass from nested sub-shells

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, scope

I am versed in using variables from a single sub-shell ... But this is a little more difficult!  What my objective is, is to set a proverbial "global" (I know they don't exist, excuse the vernacular) to be used after my `while` loop completes.  What I am trying to do, is test to see if a db table has been modified for future use in the same script -- IE

```
( while read p; do
   mysql --login-path=local -e "SELECT count(id) as row_count FROM myTable"  | ( while read row_count; do

        if [ $row_count = 0 ]
        then
           mysql --login-path=local -e"INSERT INTO someTable (this, that, other) VALUES ('$p', 'generated', 'generated');";
           echo "Inserted $p into database successfully";
           modified=1;
        fi

   done modified=$modified )

done <mytextfile 

   if [ $modified = 1 ]
      then
       # complete the stuff that needs done if the DB was modified just now
   fi
)
```

But my `$modified` variable still returns empty.  I've even tried resetting it with an if statement after the first while to no avail.  I can get it to set correctly at the end of the MySQL `while loop` but not the parent `while loop`

I know that `do while reads` and `sub-shells` can get confusing .. But I think I might be making this more convoluted than it needs to be...

Comment: If you are going to vote me down, please give me an explanation so I can better edit my original post...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a variable back from a subshell.  You just cannot.  You can get a return code, but it really is a last resort.

The best way to achieve your purpose is to keep the parts of the script you care about in the same process.

This often using a process substitution rather than a pipe, like this :

```
while IFS= read -r p
do
  while IFS= read -r row_count
  do
    if
      ((!row_count))
    then
      mysql --login-path=local -e "INSERT INTO someTable (this, that, other) VALUES ('$p', 'generated', 'generated');"
      echo "Inserted $p into database successfully"
      modified=1
     fi
  done < <(mysql --login-path=local -e "SELECT count(id) as row_count FROM myTable")
done <mytextfile 
if
  ((modified))
then
  # complete the stuff that needs done if the DB was modified just now
fi
```

A few changes compared to your code :

- Use of arithmetic expressions `(( ))` for tests (else you should double quote your variable substitutions or use `[[ ]]` for tests
- Added `-r` option to `read` statements and `IFS=`, as a general way to avoid surprises

Answer (score 0):

What you may be looking to do is export a variable. In this way you can define a variable in one script and call it in another script that doesn't know about the variable. This is done in the following ways:

```
export MYVAR
export NAME=value
```

From here your other shell script would `read` the variables.

Comment: This will allow the parent shell to provide a variable to its subshell, but will not allow the subshell to assign that variable in a way that it would be visible to the parent process.